# how to find and compare separate objects value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a React registration form.

I have the task to create input fields for form and check their values by regex and comparing values of password and repeat password with email.

It's OK but check values of password and r.password is hard

```js
const fieldsValidation = () => {
  const newState = [...fieldsState];
  for (let [index, element] of newState.entries()) {

    if (element.value.length < element.valueLength) {
      return changeFields(() => {
        newState[index].error = true;
        return newState;
      });
    }
  };
  return registerUser();
};
```

this is configuration which I'm trying to integrate with my react project

```
export const textFieldConfig = [{
    id: 'email',
    type: 'email',
    label: 'email',
    value: '',
    variant: 'outlined',
    size: 'small',
    error: false,
    helperText: 'email must include 8 char and @.',
    valueLength: 8
  },
  {
    id: 'password',
    type: 'password',
    label: 'password',
    value: '',
    variant: 'outlined',
    size: 'small',
    error: false,
    helperText: 'password must be min 6',
    valueLength: 6
  },
  {
    id: 'repeatPassword',
    type: 'password',
    label: 'repeat-password',
    value: '',
    variant: 'outlined',
    size: 'small',
    error: false,
    helperText: 'please include same password value',
    valueLength: 6
  }
];
```

Comment: Tbh, this feels like "can you do my assignment for me" type of question, usually not well received. Show your efforts and share what you tried so far

Comment: you see here wat im tryed for of loop and asked question why canot go in the next stage

Comment: imagine yourself trying to answer this question without more context: I would have to find which form solution this is (looks like material-ui verbose stuff but do I want to spend time checking ?), then I need to investigate the doc to understand what's the structure of fieldsState and its elements. That's a lot of work for something you could have provided.
And I see minimal effort in the question, so why would someone bother ?
Anyway, I hope this feedback will help you for your future questions 

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if your Object are not changing this will do

```
if(textFieldConfig[1].value == textFieldConfig[2].value){
....
}
```

Comment: in for of loop this aproach does not working i suggest becouse our array is looped already and we can acess only keys and elements